# How nimble can I make my aeroplanes?

Tags: flight, vehicles, sports

Although I'm aware of the real life existence of [aerosports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esZHktPU27k) involving planes, exactly how nimble can I expect my [planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_A6M_Zero), of a similar size, to be. If I were to design or have a racing course for said vehicles, the question is, what is the extent of the vehicular aerobatics I could require to preform to complete a race through possibly a [redwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequoiadendron_giganteum) forest.

*To summarise:*

- **This would all occur on Earth**
- **With planes of a similar size and shape to the [Japanese Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_A6M_Zero)**
- **The method of propulsion does not need to be anything specific but the size and shape of the plane must remain similar.**
- **What is most nimble I can expect my aeroplanes to be?**

Comment: I think the best answer you could get is from looking into the Red Bull Air Races. This is stunting with maximum nimbleness and often the maximum a pilot can endure G-force wise. Technology set aside, the wellbeing of your pilot would be your biggest concern.

Comment: You'll probably find better subject matter experts on this field if you look into https://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The limitation of "nimbleness" for a piloted airplane is the pilot.

A human pilot can't take prolonged G loads much over 6G, even with a G-suit and extensive training and experience.  Shorter period loads can run as high as 8G without undue hazard.  It's not particularly difficult to build an airframe that can withstand 12G positive and negative (usually, however, there's no need for the negative G rating to match the postiive, as few aircraft can generate as much G load in outside maneuvers as they do on inside).

Therefore, you can build aircraft that can take more than a human pilot -- and your limitation is about 8G positive, around 4.5 G negative, for the human pilot to remain functional continuously.

For remotely controlled aircraft (as mentioned in comments) the G limit might be up to 100G -- I've built models with wood structure that handled 20+ G positive; use of carbon fiber to improve both lightness and strength will push that figure up.  Here, the limitation is the control "loop" -- with good R/C gear, the airplane will receive pilot inputs anywhere within sight and perhaps a bit beyond -- but if the pilot can't see the airplane, and see *where it is* relative to obstacles like the trees in the question, they can't maintain adequate control, or will have to fly conservatively.

First person view doesn't help this much -- the pilot can see what the airplane "sees," but has very limited (or no) peripheral vision, no ability to look over his shoulder, limited instruments in the VR hood -- it's like playing a video game.  And with most first person setups, a single camera on the model means the pilot has no effective depth perception, even if the VR hood provides dual displays.

In the end, while a model or RPV can fly much higher performance maneuvers than a piloted craft, the other limitations may make them little if any superior to a piloted craft for an obstacle-laden race situation.

Comment: Shorter form: Aeroplanes can be much more nimble than a pilot can survive.

Comment: OP never specified a human pilot inside the plane so in theory the nimbleness is restricted to how well the operator can use the remote control.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus At that point, it's the pilot's reaction speed. So, still human pilot.

Comment: @Halfthewed yes, but the G-force is no longer a limiting factor

Comment: This may be a good question for our sister site: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Halfthawed when the humans are remote controlling the aircraft, you are indeed getting closer to what the airplane can handle. Drone and RC helicopter flying pulls off extreme stunts no human pilot could dream off. The limiting factor is hardly ever the capability of the human brain.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Well, G *is* still a limiting factor (I folded the wing on an R/C sailplane once, pulling too tight a loop while carrying ballast for windy slope soaring), but it's pretty routine for R/C planes to be able to handle 20+ G (I did that, estimated, with a sport model in the 1980s, and materials have improved since).  With carbon fiber construction, pull-pull controls, etc., an R/C plane might be able to pull 100G or more without coming apart -- but the pilot has to be able to see the plane at all times to fly it, which limits the "redwood forest" application.

Answer (score 3):

The "nimbleness" of the airplane depends a lot on how it is designed. The A6M Zero is about as nimble as any WWII era fighter of the era due to factors like power to weight ratio, wing loading, the strength of the materials used to build the aircraft and so on. You could probably build a replica A6M using composite materials, powered by a compact gas turbine engine and with modern aerodynamics (such as the wing profile and aerodynamic aids) which would be far superior in most aspects to the WWII era aircraft, but not really significantly "more" nimble.

What is needed is a clear understanding of the role the aircraft is designed to take, and for an exceptionally aerodynamic performance, the aircraft would likely not look anything like a WWII era fighter. The design would likely need to have as much mass concentrated at the center of gravity, and the wings might actually be arranged in an "X"  or "+" pattern to provide lift at any aspect. Perhaps counterintuitively, contra rotating propellers may be needed so the aircraft does not have any torque effects that affect handling one way or another. Certainly a power to weight ratio greater than 1:1 will also be needed for vertical manouevres.

One conceptual design which might fit the bill was the "[Carter Hummingbird](http://www.esotec.org/hbird/HTML/Viability_F.html)". While the designer has not actually built the aircraft, scale models were built, which should give you the idea:

[image]

*Carter Hummingbird concept scale model*

[image]

*Rear 3/4 view*

[image]

*In flight*

This is not the only possible configuration. I have seen some discussion on the "X-Planes" forum of various conceptual aircraft, some of which generate most of the lift using rotating airfoils (at that point, they are not really propellers in the way we usually think of them). Given both propulsion and lift are provided by the same system, the aircraft would be manouevred through the application of different amounts of pitch in the rotating airfoils.

Once again, there has been no actual aircraft flown in this manner (to my knowledge), although some very late WWII era German point interceptor designs like the Focke-Wulf Triebflügel or the Heinkel Wespe utilized variations of this principle. Post war "Convoy escort" fighters like the Covair "Pogo" would also have similar flight characteristics simply through the sheer power to weight ratio needed for vertical take off.

[image]

*Focke-Wulf Triebflügel*

[image]

*Heinkel Wespe*

[image]

*Covair Pogo taking off*

Of course, a jet powered aircraft can have amazing performance by adopting the vectored thrust system of the Hawker Harrier "Jump Jet". One scaled down to the size of an A6M might not be able to carry sufficient fuel for prolonged flights, however.

[image]

*AV8 Harrier in flight*

So if there is a clear understanding of the flight environment the aircraft has to perform in, then it can be designed specifically for aerobatic performance, indeed to the point that it might not even be flyable by human beings.